# Enclosing functions behaviour confusion

Tags: javascript

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  };
}

var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
//output 10
```

Can someone please explain why the 'number' parameter is not returned as undefined? I really struggle to understand how defining the variable 'twice' as a function with a fixed value 2 as its parameter can then be used as a function with passable parameter 5?

Comment: Returned as undefined at which point?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first call you are passing and fixing the factor parameter:

```
var twice = multiplier(2);
```

The parameter becomes "fixed" because the function returned by `multiplier` captures the `factor` variable value, then the reference to `factor` is lost after the `multiplier` function returns, so `factor` will never change again.

(See [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on MDN)

`twice` is now a function like this:

```
function(number) {
    return number * 2;
}
```

In the second call you are then using the `twice` function passing 5 as the number parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

When you have `var twice = multiplier(2);` is the same as:

`twice = function (number) {return number * 2};`

Imagine that Multiplier is a Class, which has a property `factor` (required to initialize the object), and when Multiplier is initialized it returns a function that takes in `number` and multiplies by `factor`.

Answer (score 2):

> defining the variable 'twice' as a function with a fixed value 2 as its

Thats not what you do there. `Twice` is just a pointer (`reference`) to the function (`closure`) inside `multiplier`.

Comment: Lets keep everything in plain C terms :) No. You are right. Pointer is not the correct term.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is javascript is called as the closure and in simplest manner 
a closure is a persistent local variable scope which allows you to access the variables that are already passed away by the execution.

So as in your example factor is local to multiplier function. But your inner function captures it and use it to compute a multiplication. At that time factor becomes a closure and it is not removed from memory. Then when you invoke the inner function(which is returned) with 5 it uses the captured variable value 2 to get the value 10. Here factor is the closure.

Closures are well explained in 'douglas crockford's javascript the good parts' book and http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/ if you like to learn more..